# get ip address apps like ADM or chrome

Tags: android, ip-address

Ip address A downloadable file or a scan that is browsed in the browser
like  network connection.apk

when download file in adm we can get ip address 
or when download file in adm in Special site and show alert or push

Answer (score 0):

Download manager on android as ADM, get copied address from clipboard, that couldn't detect automatically ip address or download links of apps